# Installation PROBLEM : Dual-boot with windows 7 on Vaio Z

Tags: system-installation, vaio

I'm trying to install 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Sony VAIO Z (specs below), which has Windows 7.

I boot my computer with the drive in and click Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the Ubuntu desktop. The welcome page asks for a language. Once the welcome page had a sentence of text, but most times I try it does not. I click continue and I do not connect to wireless then I click continue. On the Preparing to install Ubuntu page I click continue. On the Installation type page it says "This computer currently has multiple operating systems on it. What would you like to do?" The options are "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and "Something else". The one time that the welcome page had a sentence of text the corresponding Installation type page had another option that said something like "install ubuntu alongside Windows". But, as a said earlier, the page only loaded that way once and I can't reproduce the result.

I have consulted other questions, but I do not know how I should partition my drive for the installation. Additionally, I am confident that when I get past this step the problem I will have the same error that I had when I did the erase disk and install (which erased the disk completely but was unable to install because of an error "??? ???", so I had to reinstall Windows)

My questions:

1. How should I partition the drive since the install alongside windows option isn't appearing?
2. When I get to the "Install now" stage, how can I address the error "??? ???" that comes up on the "Where are you" page and persists (even if I close it many times the computer begins thinking indefinitely with a moving ubuntu wheel as the cursor. Further description: When I get to the screen asking "Where are you?" an error window titled "??? ???" comes up. I click OK and move on to enter a computer name and username and go through the Ubuntu features slide still under the "Install" window. The slides explain some features of Ubuntu. The end slide is titled "Any Questions?" At this point my cursor is an animated circular 'thinking type' cursor. The screen stays here indefinitely.

This is what I have done:

- created fresh copy of usb drive
- created fresh copy of cd
- downloaded fresh copy of amd64 .iso
- checked .iso with md5sum (correct hash)
- checked hard disk (healthy and running windows)
- tried the install as an initial option as well as clicking "Try Ubuntu" then using the desktop install icon
- tried to create usb with Unetbootin but no luck because Unetbootin does not recognize my 16gb flash drive for unknown reason

Sony Vaio Z Series VPCZ2190x: series 8 GB RAM, Intel i7 2.70GHz x 4 processor

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing more information. Please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? What is the make and model of your PC? Any further information you can provide may be helpful.

Comment: Your question is not consists enough information to help you.. Please provide some more information to understand your exat problem...

Comment: Is there any more info I should add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Sony VAIO Z series RAID configuration. It can purportedly be solved by following the instructions here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/702661-clean-install-ubuntu-12-10-sony-vaio-z-svz-2012-how.html

Note that I could not successfully complete step 13.

Comment: Perhaps RAID can be turned off?

Comment: It can but then I'm stuck with two independent hard drives, I think. I can install Ubuntu but then when I try to boot the computer it doesn't know what to do because it has two hard disks and I guess no protocol for deciding to boot the one with Ubuntu on it (the other one being wiped clean).

Comment: There is usually a way to set boot order in the BIOS. You could also physically remove the 2nd hard drive as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to combat a failed installation...

**Unreliable Internet Connection or Behind a Proxy?**
Make sure you are not connected to the Internet and try the installation again. I have found that Ubuntu will often fail when the Internet connection is week or from behind a proxy server (like at a school or business).

**Bad Installation Media?**
Formating the USB flash drive or optical disc, download a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04, check the MD5 sum (for Windows, download [this](http://download.cnet.com/MD5-SHA-Checksum-Utility/3000-2092_4-10911445.html), and for Ubuntu see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)), and write the new verfied ISO file to the freshly formatted drive or disk using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

**Bad Hard Disk?**
If you get the same message, you may have a bad hard disk. You can check this by booting to the USB drive and opening the Disk utility program. Select your hard drive, click the gear in the upper right corner, and select "SMART Data & Self Tests..." to see diagnostic info.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off my Wi-Fi connectivity and it solved the original issue of being stuck at the "Where are you" page. The further steps I was able to complete are outlined above, but I still can't complete the installation.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck now?

Comment: When I get to the screen asking "Where are you?" an error window titled "??? ???" comes up. I click OK and move on to enter a computer name and username and go through the Ubuntu features slide still under the "Install" window. The slides explain some features of Ubuntu. The end slide is titled "Any Questions?" and directs questions to askubuntu.com.

At this point my cursor is an animated circular 'thinking type' cursor. The screen stays here indefinitely.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit or 32-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using 64-bit

Comment: You may have a some errors on your installation media. Try downloading again, whiping your USB drive clean, and putting the ISO on your USB drive again. You may want to try UNetbootin this time: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried this but get the same error. Has nobody else ever experienced the error "??? ???"?

Comment: My hard disk is healthy. I confirmed that it was wiped completely clean when I tried my first Ubuntu install trial. After that I re-installed Windows.

Comment: Md5Sum gave me the correct hash value, so I think my USB disk (16 GB) is working ok. That said, it does not appear in Unetbootin, so I've had to use universal USB installer.